# How to filter Google Map Markers with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, knockout.js

I am trying to filter Map Markers via a input box. I want to do a full text sort on the markers on map markers name property.

```
<input data-bind="value: filter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

//JS

I thought I could add the markers to an array and try and clear them but it its not working. here is my markers array.

```
this.markers = ko.observableArray([]);
    //Create array of hotspot locations
    this.hotSpotList = ko.observableArray([]);
```

This adds my "hotSpot" objects to the array of hotspots

```
    initialHotSpots.forEach(function(spot){
        self.hotSpotList.push(new hotSpot(spot));
    });
```

This is the filter string that is being searched against the hotSpots name property.

```
    this.filter = ko.observable("");
```

This is the computed value of the filtered array. This part works because I can sort a list of my arrays using a foreach data-bind on the view.

```
    this.searchLocation = ko.computed(function() {
        var filter = this.filter().toLowerCase();
        if (!filter) {
            return this.hotSpotList();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.hotSpotList(), function(item){
                return item.name().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1;
            });
        }
    }, this);
```

This is creating the google map.

```
    var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.203714,-76.861046),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    var marker , i;
    var contentString = "";
    var makers

    var url = "" ;
```

This is my first attempt at trying to clear the markers before I add the new set. It just wipes them out so far and they dont show up again.

```
    // this.clearLocations = function() {
    //     for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
    //         makers[i].setMap(null)
    //     }
    // }
```

I thought if I just subscribed to the searchLocation arrays It would remove the old markers and create new ones. It works but only the first time then it does not sort the markers again if the text filter string changes.

```
    this.searchLocation.subscribe(function() {
        //Initialize marker and infowindow
        console.log('changed');
        for (i = 0; i < self.searchLocation().length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(self.searchLocation()[i].lat(), self.searchLocation()[i].lng()),
                map: map
            });

            this.markers.push(marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',(function(marker, i){
                   return function() {
                        url = self.searchLocation()[i].img();
                        contentString = "<h1>" + self.searchLocation()[i].name() + "</h1><br>" +
                        "<p>" + self.searchLocation()[i].street() + "<br>" +
                        self.searchLocation()[i].city() + ", " + self.searchLocation()[i].state() +
                         "<br>" + self.searchLocation()[i].phone() + "<br><a href='" +
                        self.searchLocation()[i].website() +"'>website</a></p><br>"
                        + "<img class='img-responsive' src='" + url + "'>";
                        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                   }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    });
    console.log(markers);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can read this answer as a reference to solve your problem: [Removing Map Pin with Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557938/removing-map-pin-with-search)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively easy way to filter markers in a list view through search box:

**HTML:**

```
  <h4>Places</h4>
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: filter" placeholder="Search for places..">
     <div>
         <ul data-bind="foreach: visiblePlaces">
             <li>
                 <input data-bind="text: address" type="button">
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
```

**JS:**

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.places = ko.observableArray(somelocations);
    this.filter = ko.observable();
    this.visiblePlaces = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.places().filter(function(place) {
            if (!self.filter() || place.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filter().toLowerCase()) !== -1)
                return place;
        });
    }, this);
```