# Filtering google map markers with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I'm trying to use a hide google maps markers using a search bar. I only want matches to show on the map, and I want non-matches to be hidden. I've tried to put the markers in an array, and hide whichever entries don't match the user input, but I cant seem to clear any of the markers. I have put my HTML below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title> Neighborhood Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="pac-input" class="controls" placeholder="Search Box" data-bind="textInput: userInput">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="listView">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: point(),foreach: markerFilter(), foreach: search()">
                <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

and here is my JavaScript:

```
    var markers = [];
    var places = [
    {
      name: 'El Camino',
      latlng: {lat: 45.415416, lng: -75.688027}
    },
    {
      name: 'Nature Museum',
      latlng: {lat: 45.412976, lng: -75.688523}
    }
    ];

    var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.points= ko.observableArray(places);

    self.Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 45.4214, lng: -75.6919},
      zoom: 15
    });

    for(var i=0; i<self.points().length; i++){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: self.points()[i].latlng,
        title: self.points().name,
        map: self.Map
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    };

    function clearMarkers(){
      for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].title.toLowerCase().index(self.userInput()) ===-1) {
          markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
      }
    }


    self.userInput = ko.observable('');


    self.search = ko.computed(function(){
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.points(), function(point){
        return point.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.userInput().toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Where is `clearMarkers` called? Maybe look at https://github.com/manuel-guilbault/knockout.google.maps ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557938/removing-map-pin-with-search